# How to store regex matches properly in C++

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I want to try the C++11 `regex` library by parsing the input in UVA985, however, I do not understand how to store all matches in a container so that I can iterate through and work with it.

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

vector<string> get_names(const string &sentence) {
    vector<string> vname;
    regex author_regex("(.+\\.\\,\\s)|(.+\\.:)", regex_constants::ECMAScript);
    smatch names; // This is always empty
    regex_match(sentence, names, author_regex); // Is this correct?
    for (auto name: names) {
        vname.push_back(name.str() + ".");
    }
    return vname;
}

int main(void) {
    const string papers[] = {
        "Smith, M.N., Martin, G., Erdos, P.: Newtonian forms of prime \
            factor matrices",
        "Erdos, P., Reisig, W.: Stuttering in petri nets",
        "Smith, M.N., Chen, X.: First oder derivates in structured programming",
        "Jablonski, T., Hsueh, Z.: Selfstabilizing data structures" };
    vector<vector<string>> input_data;
    for (auto paper : papers) {
        input_data.push_back(get_names(paper));
    }

    int counter = 1;
    for (auto scenario : input_data) {
        cout << "Paper " << counter << ":\n";
        for (auto author: scenario) {
            cout << author << endl;
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing the regex pattern into something as simple as `.`, but the container `smatch` is always empty, am I missing something?

Comment: `regex_match` only succeeds if the expression matches the complete input string. Yours doesn't. You are likely looking for `regex_search`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks, I would happily accept if you wrote it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing in a container can be done in 2 ways, range-construction and default-construction then insertion.  The `<regex>` library contains `std::sregex_token_iterator` which will return strings that match your pattern.  We can use that to range-construct and return a `std::vector<>`.

```
std::vector<std::string> names(std::sregex_token_iterator(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), author_regex),
                               std::sregex_token_iterator());
return names;
```

Now your regular expression needs some work.  Each author field in a citation is defined by a last name (`"\\w+,"`) and initials representing first/middle name (`"(\\w.)+"`).  Now, we want to do this as long as we haven't encountered a colon, so we can prefix our expression with `"(?!:)"`.  Just combining these three, we can now get all the authors names from each citation.  Unfortunately, each name beyond the first would now have a leading space. That can be removed by ignoring any leading spaces (`"[^ ]+"`). Now we combine it all and we get `"(?!:)[^ ]+\\w+, (\\w.)+"`. Your `get_names()` now looks like

```
std::vector<std::string> get_names(const std::string& sentence) {
   std::regex author_regex("(?!:)[^ ]+\\w+, (\\w.)+", std::regex_constants::ECMAScript);

   std::vector<std::string> names(std::sregex_token_iterator(sentence.begin(), sentence.end(), author_regex),
                                  std::sregex_token_iterator());
   return names;
}
```

Back in `main()`, if you want to dump the names with `std::copy()` into a `std::vector<>` with `std::back_inserter()` or into a `std::set<>` with `std::inserter()`.

```
int main() {
   const std::string citations[] = {"Smith, M.N., Martin, G., Erdos, P.: Newtonian forms of prime factor matrices",
                                    "Erdos, P., Reisig, W.: Stuttering in petri nets",
                                    "Smith, M.N., Chen, X.: First oder derivates in structured programming",
                                    "Jablonski, T., Hsueh, Z.: Selfstabilizing data structures"};
   std::set<std::string> all_authors;

   for (const auto& citation : citations) {
      auto citation_authors = get_names(citation);
      std::copy(citation_authors.begin(), citation_authors.end(), std::back_inserter(all_authors));
   }
}
```